# Lambda Layer not loading Node Module during Runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have two layers which each contain a single npm package. Neither are being recognized by Lambda as existing when testing the function. I get the error log:
[image]

The layers are

[image]

and "tensorflowJS" is a layer containing a zipped node package with tensorflowjs installed in the same runtime as the layer's function. Are there additional configurations I'm missing to run an ML model serverlessly?

Comment: i know this is an old question, but did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue right now.

Answer (score 3):

What is the structure of the files within the zip you used for these layers?

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) shows some examples:
[image]

So make sure you have a `nodejs` folder inside the zip, then a `node_modules` folder within that, then your code within that.

Comment: I have tensorflow-js.zip->nodejs->node_module-> @tensorflow + a bunch of dependencies

Comment: The folder should be named "node_modules" with an "s" at the end, not "node_module"

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. tensorflow-js.zip->nodejs->node_modules-> @tensorflow + a bunch of dependencies